# Selectively ignore files from a bower package regardless of its bower.json "ignore"

Tags: bower

Is there any way to get bower to ignore certain directories/files for download if the package does not itself use "ignore" in its bower.json?

Currently I am using a script inside of `npm` to remove the directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `init` flag to create a JSON file dynamically:

```
bower init
```

Comment: I'll give the answer to you, as that brought my attention to the `ignore` flag. Thanks!